# Are my iptables working, as I'm still seeing logs from traffic that should be blocked

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-18.04, fail2ban

Could someone please look at these rules to see if they are doing what they are supposed to be? In particular, the **f2b-MALTRAIL** one - as this is supposed to be blocking malicious traffic:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-VESTA  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22122
f2b-MALTRAIL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
fail2ban-DB  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3306,5432
fail2ban-MAIL  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587,2525,110,995,143,993
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  139.162.208.251      0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8338
DROP       tcp  --  198.11.149.1         0.0.0.0/0
DROP       tcp  --  198.11.149.124       0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  109.74.193.98        0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3306,5432
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22,22122
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,8181,2812
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21,12000:12100
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587,2525
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 143,993,110,995
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3306,5432
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-MALTRAIL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  196.52.43.59         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  196.52.43.122        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  138.197.222.97       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  195.54.160.183       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  106.12.40.74         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  157.230.38.102       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  71.6.199.23          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  206.189.88.253       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  185.234.218.85       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  92.62.131.106        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  60.220.187.113       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  159.65.196.65        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  36.112.172.125       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  202.154.180.51       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  165.227.225.195      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  104.236.72.182       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  157.230.245.91       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  106.12.82.89         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  138.197.89.212       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  218.88.215.49        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  112.122.5.6          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  92.118.161.17        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  150.109.151.206      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  46.101.220.225       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  89.248.168.112       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  196.52.43.58         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  5.8.10.202           0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  159.203.30.50        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  81.68.77.53          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  139.59.83.179        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  103.205.5.158        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  61.155.209.51        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  92.118.160.5         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  67.207.88.180        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  174.138.42.143       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  92.118.160.9         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  167.248.133.30       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  62.219.3.58          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  142.93.121.47        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  196.52.43.103        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  128.199.143.19       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  103.44.240.67        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
... removed some otherwise won't let me post!
REJECT     all  --  35.239.58.193        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  164.68.112.178       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  216.218.206.121      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  74.82.47.4           0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  74.82.47.57          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  122.228.19.79        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.129.33.129        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  104.248.229.42       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  184.105.139.93       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.148.10.186        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  178.73.215.171       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  106.12.37.20         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  104.248.176.46       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  146.88.240.4         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  116.196.105.232      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.52        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.84        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  74.82.47.22          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.166       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.192       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.133       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.39        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.149       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.56        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  212.70.149.5         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.35        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.55        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.62        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.180       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  80.82.70.118         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.93        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  212.70.149.21        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.58        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.137       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.99        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.38        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.59        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.54        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.15        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.51        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.215       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.60        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  89.248.167.131       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.121       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  212.70.149.69        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.90        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.53        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.147       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.183       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.209       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.79        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.32        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  45.142.120.74        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    
Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  197.248.10.108       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-DB (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-MAIL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  212.70.149.53        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  212.70.149.84        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  212.70.149.37        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  141.98.80.78         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  212.70.149.5         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  197.248.10.108       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-VESTA (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain vesta (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

As you can see from here, there is still active traffic showing up on our logging system:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is because my rules are not working as I'm expecting, or if all incoming network traffic would still get through and logged, even if its rejected?

**UPDATE:** In jail.conf I have:

```
[maltrail-iptables]
enabled = true
filter = maltrail
bantime = 31536000
action = iptables-allports[name=MALTRAIL, protocol=all]
;action = vesta[name=MALTRAIL]
logpath = /var/log/maltrail/*-*-*.log
maxretry = 1
```

This is correctly tracking them and adding it to the iptables list - but it seems the iptables part isn't working right

Here is what I have in iptables.rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [1450417247:318113130613]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1501717071:15015375821026]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1459728524:318650649615]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1501717071:15015375821026]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [19767360:1137058191]
:INPUT ACCEPT [11471679:654636123]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [23944491:1577314712]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [23944491:1577314712]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1459728524:318650649615]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1459728524:318650649615]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1501717071:15015375821026]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1501717071:15015375821026]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
:fail2ban-DB - [0:0]
:fail2ban-MAIL - [0:0]
:fail2ban-SSH - [0:0]
:fail2ban-VESTA - [0:0]
:vesta - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8083 -j fail2ban-VESTA
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3306,5432 -j fail2ban-DB
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,2525,110,995,143,993 -j fail2ban-MAIL
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22122 -j fail2ban-SSH
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 139.162.208.252/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8338 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 198.11.149.1/32 -p tcp -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 198.11.149.124/32 -p tcp -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 109.74.193.98/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3306,5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,22122 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,8181,2812 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,12000:12100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,2525 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 143,993,110,995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3306,5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8083 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-DB -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.74/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.147/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.149/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.79/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.192/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.209/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.133/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.121/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.99/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.166/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.180/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.93/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.51/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.84/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.53/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.90/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.60/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.15/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.137/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.39/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.62/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.58/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.35/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.183/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -s 45.142.120.38/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-MAIL -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-SSH -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-VESTA -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Nov  4 16:32:24 2020
```

Weirdly it hasn't updated for 2 days, which may explain why its not doing what I'm expecting

Answer (score 0):

The way `fail2ban` works is by looking at the logs.  Traffic has to show up there before it would be blocked (the number of times is configurable in `jail.conf`/`jail.d`).

Thus you would *expect* to see the IPs in the `f2b-` chains in the logs at some point.  However, they should stop showing up after being added to the `f2b-` chain.

Whether it is working properly really depends on the timing - when the log entries occurred versus when the addition to `f2b-` was made.

Typically ban/unban times can be found in `/var/log/fail2ban.log` but might depend on distro.

Comment: sorry I was trying to be clever and trim down the rules (there are 200+ for maltrail). I've updated my question with the full list. My boo-boo - need a coffee =)

Comment: thanks - is there a log file for iptables/fail2ban, that would show incoming traffic that has been actively blocked?

Comment: Think I'll rewrite the answer given the new data.

Comment: thanks - I think the fail2ban stuff is working ok in terms of adding the rules - but the rules don't seem to be doing what they should. I found `watch -n 2 -d iptables -nvL` on another post and this shows `Chain INPUT (policy DROP 24 packets, 1068 bytes)` changing  `Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2896 packets, 3778K bytes)
` as well - but `Chain f2b-MALTRAIL (1 references)` doesn't seem to be doing anything :/

Comment: I've updated my question with the config from jail.conf for this bit.

Comment: Ah man - I think I found it!!! I need to run `iptables-save` to update the rules file. Now its updated so lets see if the traffic gets dropped

Comment: The `f2b-` chains are added dynamically when `fail2ban` starts, so they don't need to be stored in the file.  However, good idea to leave it be for a bit, and then compare what shows up in the log to the rules.